# How to match on single line for regex?

Tags: java, regex

I have a `regex` to match a line and delete it. Everything is below it (and keep everything above it).

> ```
> Two Part Ask:
>
> 1) Why won't this pattern match the given String text below?
> 2) How can I be sure to just match on a single line and not multiple lines?
>    - The pattern has to be found on the same single line.
> ```

```
    String text = "Keep this.\n\n\nPlease match junkhere this t-h-i-s is missing.\n"
            + "Everything should be deleted here but don't match this on this line" + "\n\n";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(Please(\\s)(match)(\\s)(.*?)\\sthis\\s(.*))$", Pattern.DOTALL );
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    if (m.find()) {
        text = (m.replaceAll("")).replaceAll("[\n]+$", "");  // remove everything below at and below "Please match ... this"
        System.out.println(text);
    }
```

Expected Output:

> Keep this.

Comment: What's the expected output? What output are you receiving?

Comment: If you want `^` and `$` to match resp. at the beginning of each line/at the end of each line you must use `Pattern.MULTILINE`. `Pattern.DOTALL` makes the dot match newlines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are complicating your life...

First, as I said in the comment, use `Pattern.MULTILINE`.

Then, to truncate the string from the beginning of the match, use `.substring()`:

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^Please\\s+match\\b.*?this",
    Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
return m.find() ? input.substring(0, m.start()) : input;
```

Comment: awesome! yeah, got it working with multiline. not regex savvy at all. i like your solution....and yes I was complicating my life quite a bit apparently. =)

Comment: qq: why don't you need an anchor $ and wha tis the \\b?

Comment: 1. because, from your regex, it appeared that you wanted to match a line _beginning_ with something; as the rest of the input was to be truncated, there was no need to match the full line; 2. it is the word anchor (match at the beginning or end of a word).

Comment: k very helpful, but when I run your solution the resulting it matched but the substring chomps everything (returns "")

Comment: Uh yes, sorry... Edited.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `DOTALL` to make sure to match on a single line and convert `\s` to `" "`

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(Please( )(match)( )(.*?) this (.*))$");
```

- `DOTALL` makes a dot match newlines as well
- `\s` can match any whitespace including new lines.

Comment: thanks! ok that makes sense per DOITALL and the //s but what does MULTILINE do (even though it's not in there)?

Comment: also what if there was input like "xxthisxx"...how can I just make sure to match whole words only?

Comment: `MULTILINE` lets you use anchors `^` and `$` for matching each line in a an multiple line input.

Comment: Since we have `<space>this<space>` in pattern therefore it won't match `this123` or `abcdthis`

Comment: ok use: `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?m)^(Please +match +.*? this (.*))$");` Here `(?m)` is for `MULTILINE`